# How can I use MonoGame/OpenTK with good performance?

Tags: raspbian, opengles

I'm making a system UI in C# OpenTK. Everything compiles correctly and it runs on the Raspberry Pi, but the performance is unbearable.I get less than one frame per second.

I'm on a raspberry pi 2 (latest firmware), and libegl hack for x11 doesn't work for me, there's a bunch of missing files when I try to `sh` it.

What steps do I need to take to make my OpenTK program run smoothly?

Comment: short answer: don't run it on a Pi.

Comment: There was some work with impressive results in 2011 and 2012 which i fear has stalled : http://blog.phault.net/2012/10/open-source-and-net-at-monkeyspace-2012/

Comment: Would you post the error messages you get?